# How to get android constraint-layout-solver 1.0.2 source?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to know from where I could find the sources for "constraint-layout-solver 1.0.2 ". I would need this information to download the source code and perform analysis on the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can get source JAR file from this [URL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support.constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2)

If you find what you looking is from this URL please do not forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi there, The URL which you have given is not the source code URL but its where i can download the binary which i already have it. I need the URL where i could download the source code. Thanks for your try :)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, the solver isn't open source.